# Python regex iteration for all combinations

Tags: python, regex, iteration, combinations

I am new to regex. I am using Python 2.7 and BeautifulSoup4. I want to iterate over a particular regular expression.

**Required ouput :**

> length : 5 , expression : [a-zA-Z0-9!&#%@]
>   
>   
>  It should try all possible combinations e.g:
>   
>  ['aaaaa','aaaab','aaaac',...,'aaaaz','aaaaA',...,'aaaaZ','aaaa0','aaaa9','aaaa!','AAA!!']
>   
>   
>  Moreover this should be possible too. If the expression is orange\d{1}
>  
>   
>  ['orangea','oranges']]

I tried this:

```
 regexInput = "a-z0-9"
 #regexInput = "a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&"
 comb = itertools.permutations(regexInput,passLength)
 for x in comb:
    ''.join(x)
```

I realized that this is a totally wrong approach as these are just permutations. Please help. Sorry for bad explaination, very frustrated.

Comment: So you want to get all words that could be generated by the regex ? ie, the entire set of words that the regex can detect ?

Comment: Yes, and for this I don't even know what should be my search query in Google. Moreover its like a stupid dictionary which checks every possible combination of mentioned length. Well in addition to that it should check symbols and digits.

Comment: Please don't down vote. I am looking for genuine help. If this question is asked earlier mark it duplicate. If its new, it might happen to be an interesting thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Itertools functions for permutations or combinaisons takes a series of elements as first parameter. It cannot generate the serie for you (from `a-z` to `abc...xyz`). Fortunatly `string` offer some constants like `ascii_letters` that contain `a-zA-Z`.

If your goal is to interpret the regex and generate every cases, ... It's pretty hard and you should explain the *why?* before we go further.

If you just want to get combinaisons for alphabetical letters:

```
import string
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

result = combinations_with_replacement(string.ascii_letters, 5)

#comb = [''.join(n) for n in result] # warning, heavy processing

print [''.join(result.next()) for _ in range(10)]
# > ['aaaaa', 'aaaab', 'aaaac', 'aaaad', 'aaaae', 'aaaaf', 'aaaag', 'aaaah', 'aaaai', 'aaaaj']
```

You can replace `string.ascii_letters` with any serie of characters.

Comment: @AakashShah if this answers your question, then mark it as accepted. Otherwise try to explain what's missing from the answer.

Comment: @AakashShah - I edited my answer to point out what was wrong with your usage of itertools.

Comment: @Cyrbil Thanks for the swift responses. Your explanation matched my question, perfectly. I am making a captcha bot reader. I need to make a complete database for a reference table. If I could do it with regex, I don't mind keeping it on for months till it finishes the database file. This is the reason I havnt accepted your answer.

Comment: You imported `combinations_with_replacement` but used it as `itertools.combinations_with_replacement`